# count number of items in a list within list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have got a list which contains lists as per the example below

```
h = [[('red', array([ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.])),
      ('blue', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]))],
     [('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]))],
     [('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  0.]))]]
```

How can I count the number of items based on their label in each sublist. Say the number of items in `h[1]` containing `'red'` equals 10? The example above contains two sublists one contains three elements and the other one one. 
        So count no of items in h[0] contains 'red' would give 2 and in h[1] = 1

Comment: Number of items in a list within list or number of items in a list within a list within a tuple?

Comment: Hi msvalkon,
no of items in a list within not within tuple

Comment: Show us a concrete example of your data.

Comment: Can you show an example of input and expected output?

Comment: Your list has only one sublist..so there is no h[1]

Comment: What would be the output if `h = [('red', array([0, 1, 2])), ('blue', array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7])), ('green', array([8, 9]))]`?

Comment: I have provided an example

Comment: Now your example makes absolutely no sense. You have a tuple in the middle of two lists there. If you cannot give us a concrete, working example of your data and if you cannot coherently explain what your problem is, there's a fair chance we can't help you.

Comment: h[0] is a list containing two tuples, where each tuple contains a string and an array. One of those strings is 'red' and the other is 'blue'. Why would the count of 'red' be 2?

Answer (score 1):

If your data structure is like:

```
goat = [('a', np.array([1,2,3])), ('b', np.array([1,2]))]
```

Then you can have:

```
[(i, len(list(j))) for i, j in goat]
```

and the output will be:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 2)]
```